# Meteor JS cannot sort data

Tags: javascript, sorting, meteor

I have a button in the body that when clicked, should sort descending.  When I do, nothing happens.  I believe my code is correct, but perhaps I'm missing something?

Here's the js:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

Template.body.events({
"click .sort_title": function () {
return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {movie_title: -1}});
console.log('Sorting has been clicked');
}
});
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<table class="item_db">
<tr>
<th>Title <i class="fa fa-sort sort_title"></i></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

clicking the button doesn't even pass to the console log command, so it breaks at the task.

Comment: try moving the `console.log()` above the return statement to confirm that the event is really not firing. if it does fire the log, then maybe the problem is in your `Tasks.find()` code.

Comment: when I remove the tasks.find() it works, so yeah it definitely is firing, but I can't seem to understand why return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {movie_title: -1}}); isn't working, since the initial sort works:

     Template.body.helpers({
     tasks: function () {
     return Tasks.find({});
      }});

Comment: The console.log won't ever get hit because the `return` statement is before it. Are you sure you have the field name `movie_title` right? The code looks right to me as well.

Comment: yes, the field name is correct, when I put it on the initial Tasks.find in Template.body.helpers it will sort, but I only want to sort it when the button is clicked.

Comment: If you run Tasks.find({}) in the browser console, will it return all your tasks? Do you have autopublish or insecure packages removed? Also, when you click it does nothing happen, no console message or anything?

Comment: Autopublish and Insecure are not yet removed.

If I put the `console.log()` before the `return Tasks.find` it will give me a result in the log, but not the other way around.

Comment: when I manually punch `return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {movie_title: -1}});` into the console, it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is the helper which is responsible for returning the tasks to display isn't receiving the sort toggle. By setting a `Session` value in the click event it will force the task helper, which is using the same `Session` key, to run again. See below for an example, as well as [Meteor's documentation on reactivity](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivity).

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

Template.body.events({
  "click .sort_title": function () {
    var sortValue = Session.get('sort') || 1;
    Session.set('sort', sortValue * -1);
  }
});

Template.body.helpers({ 
  tasks: function () {
    var sortValue = Session.get('sort') || 1;
    return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {movie_title: sortValue}}); 
  }
});
```

Comment: I knew it had to do with Sessions!  Thank you very much.

Comment: Valuable example! Thanks!