# Sorting by nested value in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the following function:

```
function(field,order){
  if(field==="date"){
    return Tasks.find({},{sort:{createdAt:order}});
  }else{
    return Tasks.find({},{sort:{turtlelog.field:order}});
  }
}
```

The first condition works just fine. But the else body doesn't like that dot notation.

Any idea what is the correct notation?

Comment: Try this `{sort:{turtlelog: {field: order}}}`.

Comment: or `'turtlelog.field': order`

Comment: Tried both before and none worked.

Comment: I tried to do 'turtlelog.'+field in a new variable but it wasnt working.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270992/meteor-js-cannot-sort-data) *might* be helpful.

Comment: Ok so I think I get what's wrong. I just don't know how to solve it.  When I use turtlelog.field:order it is just looking for the field property inside the turtlelog object, instead of evaluating using the field parameter that I'm supplying. The question then becomes, strangely, how do I pass an evaluated variable into this query?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was pretty close but you guys definitely helped:

By using object literal notation I could not evaluate the field parameter.
I used the following:

```
function(field,order){
  console.log(field);
  console.log(order);
  if(field==="date"){
    return Tasks.find({},{sort:{createdAt:order}});
  }else{
    var orderString = order>0?"asc":"desc";
    var field='turtlelog.'+field;
    var sort = {sort:[field,orderString]}
    return Tasks.find({},sort);
  }
}
```

I used an alternative notation for the sorting object, and now it's working.

Comment: I was just about to suggest this for the else clause: `var o = {};
o[turtlelog[field]] = order; return Tasks.find({},{sort: o});`. I'd love to know if this actually works.

Comment: `o['turtlelog.'+field]` instead of  `o[turtlelog[field]]` works